# Does developing on ARM Processors from different vendors differ much?

Tags: arm

I have started developing applications on XMC 2 go evaluation board. I, more or less, got the idea. But what if I try to go for, lets say, STM32?

For XMC1100 setting pin 00 as output is

```
PORT1->IOCR0 &= ~PORT0_IOCR0_PC0_Msk;
PORT0->IOCR0 |= 0x0 << PORT0_IOCR0_PC0_Pos;
```

But I don't think stm32 has a `IOCR` register. So, should an engineer learn all these different register names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it does. While all Cortex M controllers will share the same core, and some of the core peripherals, all other peripherals are vendor specific.

Even using CMSIS won't help you much in that scenario as it will only cover things provided by ARM, which is the core and the core peripherals (NVIC, Systick...)

So in the end if you switch from one vendor to another, you will have to read the data sheet, the reference (or user) manual and figure out how stuff works. You don't necessarily have to learn every register names as vendors now provide peripheral libraries which put an abstract layer on top of the hardware.

But it's not hard or challenging, it's what you gotta do - I'd say it's even one of the more fun parts figuring out how those peripherals work.

And after you realized this, you might want to write a Hardware Abstraction Layer to prevent your firmware being completely unusable for another controller. If you have a stable HAL, you can at least get the device drivers and application layers over to your next controller and only have to implement the HAL again.

Even though the vendors offer peripheral libraries, which function as a HAL, there is no standard across vendors. So at the lowest level you will have to adapt your software, which is why I said, that you yourself might want to write a HAL (in which you can use the HAL of the vendor).

If you want to implement a stable HAL, your features will most likely be limited to the very basic functionality of the common peripherals, so every controller can be abstracted. Typically you will loose some more advanced features of the peripherals, because they are not available everywhere (say a baudrate detection mechanism or automatic dead time between PWM channels). That will be the price to pay. If we need those mechanisms for our application, we write a specialized hardware driver for that purpose, so the rest can still work with the common HAL.

Using this approach I ported an application to two other microcontrollers just implementing the HAL, the rest could be compiled without a single change in the software.

Comment: I appreciate that you mentioned HAL. How about HALs that vendors provide? Do they obey some kind of standard across processors?

Comment: @ozgur To put it mildly is "no". Vendor specific HALs are just there to allow you to work with all of their chips with the same commands. Such as Atmel Software Framework, which is a very nice quick-proto toolset, has some functions the same as other vendor HALs, but nothing is guaranteed and indeed I have not been able to do without my own HAL or HALAL (<- LOL!) to abstract their abstraction.

Comment: @ozgur I have updated my post and expanded it on vendor HALs, I agree with Asmyldof, there is no standard.

Comment: @Arsenal Helpful a lot. Thank you very much, really.

Comment: @Asmyldof now your comment's message is clear. a lack of standard is a shame, though.

Comment: @ozgur It's very annoying, but unfortunately market workings also make inter-standardisation less likely. If I am Atmel and make a nice and free dev suite, that churns out ARM code that runs equally well on an ST or NXP, then you see much lower return on investment for that suite. Whereas having the best suite now helps sell your chips, which creates a sort of "arms race" between vendors to keep their suites well equipped. It would have to come from the ARM corp, if any obligations are to be made, I fear.

Comment: @Asmyldof that makes sense. So in the end, you probably end up working with a processor series from a specific vendor and stick with that until a very big reason to change arise. Thats how it works, then.

Comment: @Zgrkpnr you will probably first check if a already used series (better yet an already used MCU) will fit your requirements, and only if it doesn't (price can also be a requirement) you switch to another. This approach can save time and headaches.